# Cleaning horrible looking repeated try excepts

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way to make this horrible mess look nice? The issue was that some times it would return an empty dataframe and therefore could not be converted to a float. Even if it could return zero that would be no good so i made it a small value 0.0001 to avoid zeros in the denominator.

Thanks

```
cities = list(set(nlp_inst.raw_data_frames['SKY_modified']['City'].unique()))
mapping_data = []

for city in cities:
    try:
        lat = float(pos_df[pos_df['City']==city]['Latitude'].unique())
    except:
        lat = np.nan
    try:
        long = float(pos_df[pos_df['City']==city]['Longitude'].unique())
    except:
        long = np.nan
    try:
        city_count_pos = pos_df[pos_df['City']==city].count()[0]
    except:
        city_count_pos = 0.0001
    try:
        city_count_neg = neg_df[neg_df['City']==city].count()[0]
    except:
        city_count_neg = 0.0001
    mapping_data.append([lat, long, city_count_pos/(city_count_pos+city_count_neg)])
    print(mapping_data[-1])
```

Comment: What exactly is the empty dataframe, is it `null` or `""` or what?

Comment: literally 0 rows

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific way to exactly manipulate various `try` and `except`. However, here's an approach that I'll recommend you to use:

```
cities = list(set(nlp_inst.raw_data_frames['SKY_modified']['City'].unique()))
mapping_data = []
for city in cities:
    cords = [pos_df[pos_df['City']==city]['Latitude'].unique(), pos_df[pos_df['City']==city]['Longitude'].unique()] # [lat, long]
    for i in range(len(cords)): 
        if not cords[i]: cords[i] = np.nan # checks if cord is not null | you can replace this with your empty set
        else: cords[i] = float(cords[i])
    city_count_int = [pos_df[pos_df['City']==city].count(), neg_df[neg_df['City']==city].count()] # [pos, neg]
    for j in range(len(city_count_int)):
        if not city_count_int[j]: city_count_int[j] = 0.0001
        else: city_count_int[j] = city_count_int[j][0]
    mapping_data.append([lat, long, city_count_pos/(city_count_pos+city_count_neg)])
    print(mapping_data[-1])
```

You can also create a basic function to clear the cluster.

*Note: The above code is written considering your empty set means None*